# Крестик как в google chrome c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли создать крестик для закрытия вкладок, как в Chrome для Windows Forms (`TabPage`)

Comment: [Страдайте](https://habrahabr.ru/post/170375/) или переходите на WPF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15050635/5045688

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогло

Comment: Подскажите как подобное реализовать на WPF